# Add 'option' in 'select' using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to automate a project.
Current code snippet is

```
<SELECT onchange="getDeviceCount('update', 'inputForm')" id=updateVersion style="WIDTH: 540px" name=updateVersion></SELECT>
```

Options were supposed to be added to this 'select' element by using a function but the function call has been bypassed.
I want to add option in this select webelement and need to change the code snippet to

```
<SELECT onchange="getDeviceCount('update', 'inputForm')" id=updateVersion style="WIDTH: 540px" name=updateVersion>

<OPTION selected value=I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2>I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2</OPTION>

</SELECT>
```

Is it possible to do it via selenium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code to modify innerHTML of target Select node:

```
driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById('updateVersion').innerHTML='<OPTION selected value="I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2">I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2</OPTION>';""")
```

Comment: thanks. This code working for chrome but leads to this in IE . 
<SELECT onchange="getDeviceCount('update', 'inputForm')" id=updateVersion style="WIDTH: 540px" name=updateVersion>I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2</OPTION></SELECT>

Comment: You mean that there is no opening tag for Option? Try `driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById('updateVersion').outerHTML='<SELECT onchange="getDeviceCount(\'update\', \'inputForm\')" id=updateVersion style="WIDTH: 540px" name=updateVersion>
<OPTION selected value="I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2">I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2</OPTION>
</SELECT>';""")`. Does it work?

Comment: throwing Javascript error. BTW any idea why this code is working in chrome but not in IE ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, wrong quotes... try `driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById('updateVersion').outerHTML='<SELECT onchange="getDeviceCount(\"update\", \"inputForm\")" id=updateVersion style="WIDTH: 540px" name=updateVersion> <OPTION selected value="I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2">I9192DDSCQD1.DM/I9192ODDCOF2/I9192DDUCOF2</OPTION> </SELECT>';""")`. In IE there are several restrictions and AFAIK innerHTML of read-only nodes cannot be modified, but I'm not sure whether this is really the root-cause

Comment: Thanks :) working now. BTW what was wrong in using ' with escape character ? My guess is when """ string """ was getting executed in javascript , escape character was removed and this led to error ?

Comment: I don't think that problem is `"""` - it seem like an inconsistent usage of single quotes...

Comment: My Theory is """ is not the problem. But when content inside """ is sent to javascript for execution, escape char is removed as we go inside """ . Then while executing javascript no escape char causes error.
However i am not sure and am just a newbie in this.
What do you mean by "inconsistent usage of single quotes" and how it can be reconised and avoided ?

Comment: I mean that if to mix quotes as `'some "text \'with\' mixed" quotes'` you will see `\'with\'`, so we need to mix quotes as `'some "text \"with\" mixed" quotes'` to get `"with"` (without slashes). `"""` or `'''` usually just used to declare piece of text with new lines or to ignore quotes escaping - just like in my code...